# Trying to break out off loop and go to starting_point() with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

```
import os

import sys

import tkinter as tk

from selenium import webdriver

import keyboard

from tkinter import messagebox

import random

from time import sleep

#from fake_useragent import UserAgent

from selenium_stealth import stealth

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

running = True

# import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
# from google.api_core.exceptions import InvalidArgument

# # Set up the Dialogflow client
# session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()
# session_path = session_client.session_path(<project_id>, <session_id>)

# # Set up the query text and parameters
# text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=<query_text>, language_code='en-US')
# query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

# # Send the query to Dialogflow and retrieve the response
# try:
#     response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session_path, query_input=query_input)
#     fulfillment_text = response.query_result.fulfillment_text
# except InvalidArgument:
#     fulfillment_text = 'Sorry, I did not understand your query.'

# # Do something with the fulfillment text, such as store it in a variable
# my_variable = fulfillment_text

class TinderBot():

    def __init__(self):

        path =  "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
        service = Service(executable_path=path)
        #web = 'https://tinder.com/'

        options = Options()
        options.add_experimental_option('debuggerAddress', 'localhost:4444')
        options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

    def open_tinder(self):
        self.driver.get("https://tinder.com")
    
        sleep(3)

        try:
            if self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"):
                gold_advertizement = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', gold_advertizement)
                
                self.driver.execute_script("document.title = '9515';")

                sleep(random.randint(3,4))

                bot.starting_point()
            
            else: 
                
                self.driver.execute_script("document.title = 'Port9515';")

                sleep(random.randint(3,4))
                
                bot.starting_point()
    
        except:
            
            self.driver.execute_script("document.title = 'Port9515';")

            sleep(random.randint(3,4))

            bot.starting_point()


    def make_it_flick(self):

        try:
            
            while True:
                
                #self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/likes-you")
                
                #list_of_likes = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
                sleep(random.randint(4,5))
                

                open_card = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/div')
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', open_card)

                sleep(random.randint(2,4))

                swipe_right = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/button')
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', swipe_right)
        except:
          
                #root = tk.Tk()
                #root.withdraw()

                #messagebox.showinfo("Title", "User input needed")
            try:
                self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/likes-you")
                #bot.make_it_flick()
                if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
                    bot.starting_point()
                else:
                    bot.make_it_flick()

                
                    
                # while True:

                #self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/likes-you")
                
                # #list_of_likes = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]')
                #     sleep(random.randint(4,5))
                

                #     open_card = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/span/div')
                #     self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', open_card)

                #     sleep(random.randint(2,4))

                #     swipe_right = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[4]/button')
                #     self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', swipe_right)
            except:    
                #bot.starting_point()
                keyboard.add_hotkey("n", stop_execution)
        
                        
    def like_who_like_you(self):
        
        self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/likes-you")

        sleep(random.randint(3,4))

        try:
            if self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/button'):

                x_on_boost_for_more_likes = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/main/div/div[2]/div[3]/button')
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', x_on_boost_for_more_likes)
                bot.make_it_flick()
                
            else:
                bot.make_it_flick()   
                
        except:
            bot.make_it_flick()
           






            #see_who_liked_you = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/aside/nav[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/div/div[1]/div')
            #self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', see_who_liked_you)




    def fuck_the_competition(self):
        rbg = 'lesbian'
        while rbg == 'lesbian':

            #self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs")
            sleep(random.randint(4,6))

            i_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/button | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', i_button)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))
            
            report_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', report_button)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            next_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', next_button)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))      

            bruh_thats_a_minor = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/div/ul/li[3]/span/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', bruh_thats_a_minor)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            report_next = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', report_next)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            i_know_them_bro_they_minors = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/div/ul/li[5]/span/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', i_know_them_bro_they_minors)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            final_next_hehehe = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', final_next_hehehe)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            the_deets = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/div/textarea')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', the_deets)
            the_deets.send_keys("I know them from my hometown. They are still in High school.")
            final_submit = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', final_submit)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            submit_report = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', submit_report)

            sleep(random.randint(2,3))

            done = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[2]/main/div/form/footer/button')
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', done)

            sleep(random.randint(3,5))

    def first_message(self):
        sleep(random.randint(2,4))
        text_box = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/form/textarea | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/form/textarea | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/button')
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', text_box) 
        #send input
        text_box.send_keys("hey, how are you")
        #send keyboard input
        text_box.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        submit_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[3]/form/button')  
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', submit_button)

    def right_swipe(self):
        like_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/button | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/button | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[4]/button")
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', like_button)
        like_button.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
    # def left_swipe(self):
    #      doc = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[4]/button/span/span/svg/path')
    #      doc.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_LEFT)

    def auto_swipe(self):
        self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs")
        sleep(random.randint(2,3))

        #pause()

        while True:   
            try:
                sleep(random.randint(2,4))
                self.right_swipe()
                
            except:
                try:
                    self.first_message()
                except:
                    self.starting_point()

    def send_message_to_matches(self):
        try:
            while True:
                matches_button = self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/aside/nav[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/button')
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', matches_button)

                first_in_line = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/aside/nav[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/a | /html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/aside/nav[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/a")
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', first_in_line)

                text_box_for_first_in_line = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/form/textarea")
                self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', text_box_for_first_in_line)

                text_box_for_first_in_line.send_keys("hey, my tinder is on my desktop, lets talk on insta im @jexplorarelmundo")
                text_box_for_first_in_line.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

                sleep(random.randint(2,3))
        except:
            button_to_get_to_swiper = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/aside/nav[1]/div/a/span")
            self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button_to_get_to_swiper)
            bot.starting_point()

    def starting_point(self):
        #input_text = input("Welcome to Jay's Tinder Bot, Where we all fuck the shit out of Tinder together since they are disingenuous criminals that abuse men's self esteem to further their bottom line..... Did I mention I dont feel guity about this?    Nevertheless, select 1 to start using the AutoSwiper, 2 to automate messaging to your matches, 3 to Fuck THE Competition, and 4 to AutoMatch ------------------ JayVercetti'")

        import tkinter as tk

            # Close the existing window, if it exists
        try:
            self.window.destroy()
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        # Create the main window
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.window.title("TBot")

        # Define a function to execute when button 1 is clicked
        def button1_clicked():
            print("Button 1 clicked")
            try:
                if self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]") or self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/button[2]"):
                    gold__platinum_advertizement = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2 | /html/body/div[2]/main/div/button[2]")
                    self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', gold__platinum_advertizement)
                    bot.auto_swipe()
                else: 
                    bot.auto_swipe()
            except:
                bot.auto_swipe
                
            
            #bot.open_tinder()
            #sleep(random.randint(2,3))
            bot.auto_swipe()
        # Define a function to execute when button 2 is clicked
        def button2_clicked():
            print("Button 2 clicked")
            self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs")
            sleep(random.randint(4,6))

            try:
                if self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"):
                    gold_advertizement = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
                    self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', gold_advertizement)
                    bot.send_message_to_matches()
                else: 
                    bot.send_message_to_matches()
            except:
                bot.send_message_to_matches()

        # Define a function to execute when button 3 is clicked
        def button3_clicked():
            print("Button 3 clicked")
            sleep(random.randint(4,6))
        #try:
            #self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/button')
            # try:
            #     if self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]"):
            #         gold_advertizement = self.driver.find_element('xpath', "/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/button[2]")
            #         self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', gold_advertizement)
                    # try:
                    #     if self.driver.find_element('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/main/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/button')

            bot.fuck_the_competition()
            #     else: 
            #         bot.fuck_the_competition()
            # except:
            #     bot.fuck_the_competition()        
            #except:
                #self.driver.get("https://tinder.com/app/recs")

        def button4_clicked():
            print("Button 4 clicked")
            sleep(random.randint(3,4))
            bot.like_who_like_you()


        def button5_clicked():
            print("Button 5 clicked")
            sleep(random.randint(3,4))
            self.driver.get("https://www.help.tinder.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=360000234452")


        def button6_clicked(): 
            print("Button 6 clicked")
            sleep(random.randint(3,4))
            #bot.starting_point()
            
            sys.exit()

        # Define a function to check which button was clicked and execute the appropriate code
        def handle_button_click(button_number):
            if button_number == 1:
                button1_clicked()
            elif button_number == 2:
                button2_clicked()
            elif button_number == 3:
                button3_clicked()
            elif button_number == 4:
                button4_clicked()
            elif button_number == 5:
                button5_clicked()
            elif button_number == 6:
                button6_clicked()
        # def on_stop():
        #     global running
        #     running = False
        # Create the buttons and add them to the window
        button1 = tk.Button(self.window, text="AutoSwipe", command=lambda: handle_button_click(1))
        button2 = tk.Button(self.window, text="AutoMessage", command=lambda: handle_button_click(2))
        button3 = tk.Button(self.window, text="AutoReport", command=lambda: handle_button_click(3))
        button4 = tk.Button(self.window, text="AutoMatch", command=lambda: handle_button_click(4))
        button5 = tk.Button(self.window, text="Refund", command=lambda: handle_button_click(5))
        button6 = tk.Button(self.window, text="STOP", command=lambda: handle_button_click(6))

        # Pack the buttons into the window
        button1.pack(pady=10)
        button2.pack(pady=10)
        button3.pack(pady=10)
        button4.pack(pady=10)
        button5.pack(pady=10)
        button6.pack(pady=10)

        # Start the main event loop
        self.window.mainloop()

#

#running = True

# def stop():
#     if button_number == 6:
#         button6_clicked()

os.system('clear')

def stop_execution():
    bot.starting_point()

# keyboard.add_hotkey("a", stop_execution)

# if __name__ == "__main__":
    
bot = TinderBot()
bot.open_tinder()
#     keyboard.wait()

# import threading
# import keyboard
# from tkinter import *

# def stop_execution():
#     bot.starting_point()

# def hotkey_listener():
#     keyboard.add_hotkey("a", stop_execution)
#     keyboard.wait()

# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     bot = TinderBot()
#     bot.open_tinder()

#     # start the hotkey listener in a separate thread
#     t = threading.Thread(target=hotkey_listener)
#     t.start()

#     # run the tkinter mainloop in the main thread
#     mainloop()









#/html/body/div[2]/main/div/button[2]  platnum sub maeby later button
```

how would make button6 break the loop in autoswipe and automatch and then go to starting_point again.  I tried many things but they all failed to work will the autoswipe and automatch loops where running.

Additionally when any of the loops are being executed I don't even have the option of pressing the STOP (button6) button since the loop is being executed and all I get when I hover my cursor over the tkinter window is a rotating circle for a cursor.

Ultimately I need to be able to hit the stop button to break out of the loops described above and demonstrated in the code and then call the starting_point function.

Thanks,
Jay

Comment: Is it possible to cut the size of the code down a bit? Is all of that code _really_ necessary for this specific question about breaking out of a loop?

Comment: This is a valid concern.  I am new to this all and have been using chatgpt to build this script.  I honestly have been getting errors left and right over the most minor things I did not realize impacted the rest of the code.  I put it all there so that you have a full picture.

Comment: This is actually a great demonstration for why you should not rely on chatgpt.

Comment: hence im here today on stack overflow. so far chatgpt has been more usefull and required less effort.